# Jquery sound notification on new file content

Tags: jquery, file, audio

I've tried looking for similar problem but can't find the answer here.

I want to give a sound notification every time content of a file is changed. The file is called using jquery every second.

The code i've come up with, gives an error that always give the sound per second, it seems the value of the div is empty, thus it's considered as different each time and the sound is played.

Can somebody fix this for me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tmp;
$(document).ready(function(){refreshTable();});
function refreshTable(){
    tmp=$("#tableHolder2").val();
    $.get("temp1.php", doSomethingWithData);
}

function doSomethingWithData(data) {
    if(tmp!=data){
        $("#tableHolder2").text(data);
        var sound = new Audio('bell_ring.ogg');
        sound.play();
    }
    $("#tableHolder").text(data);
    setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
}
</script>

<div id="tableHolder"></div>
<div id="tableHolder2"></div>
```

The temp1.php is a normal text file with any content. It's returned ok with no error. The problem is with the sound. It keeps firing sound, not only on data change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally able to get the code working. I'm posting the answer so that it can be used by others later on.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tmp="";
sound = new Audio('bell_ring.ogg');
$(document).ready(function(){refreshTable();});
function refreshTable(){
    $.get("temp1.php",withData);
    setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
}
function withData(data) {
    if(tmp!=data){
        sound.play();
        tmp=data;
    }
    $("#tableHolder").html(data);
}
</script>
```